# have two fields and how to make anyone is mandatory in pydantic model in fastapi

Tags: python, validation, fastapi, pydantic

```
class User(BaseModel):
     id: int
     name: str
     email: Optinal[str]
     age: int
     place1: str
     place2: str
```

This is my model class and here **place1** and **place2** are two fields i need compulsorily one field but either place1 or place2. so if i have get place1 then no need place2 and vice versa how to validate this.

thanks for all inputs.